# How to aggregate from result data Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have table :

```
+------+-------+-----------------+
| id   | name  | code   | desc   |
+------+-------+-----------------+
| 1    | aa    | 032016 | grape  |
| 1    | aa    | 012016 | apple  |
| 1    | aa    | 032016 | grape  |
| 1    | aa    | 022016 | orange |
| 1    | aa    | 012016 | apple  |
| 1    | aa    | 032016 | grape  |
+------+-------+-----------------+
```

i tried with query:

```
SELECT id, name, code, desc, COUNT(code) as view
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, name, code, desc
```

and the result is :

```
+------+-------+------------------------+
| id   | name  | code   | desc   | view |
+------+-------+------------------------+
| 1    | aa    | 012016 | apple  | 2    |
| 1    | aa    | 022016 | orange | 1    |
| 1    | aa    | 032016 | grape  | 3    |
+------+-------+------------------------+
```

what i expected is like this :

```
+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | name  | code                 | desc               | view   |
+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1    | aa    | 012016,022016,032016 | apple,orange,grape | 2,1,3  |
+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

can anyone help me how to aggregate the result?
thanks in advance

Comment: check LISTAGG function for oracle 11g onwards

Comment: sql server is different than oracle, please use tags properly

Comment: You shouldn't use `desc` for a column name, by the way, as it's a keyword in SQL. I *suppose* the parser can deal with that, but it is safer not to use it. It can be confusing to the reader and possibly to the system as well (as in `order by code desc, desc, name desc`).

Comment: `view` is also a keyword in SQL by the way. It should be less of a problem, because it is only used in DDL and not in DML as far as I am aware. I would not use it anyway to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table design has me a bit worried. Is it coincidence that one fruit always has the same code in the table? Then why store it redundantly? There should be a fruit table holding each fruit and its code only once. You know why this is called a *relational* database system, don't you?

However, with your query you are almost where you wanted to get. You have the counts per id, name, code, and desc. Now you want to aggregate even further. So in the next step group by id and name, because you want one result row per id and name it seems. Use `LISTAGG` to concatenate the strings in the group:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  name, 
  listagg(code, ',') within group(order by code) as codes,
  listagg(desc, ',') within group(order by code) as descs,
  listagg(view, ',') within group(order by code) as views
FROM
(
  SELECT id, name, code, desc, COUNT(*) as view
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY id, name, code, desc
)
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY id, name;
```

Comment: well it's a bit complicated on my real database, i once thinking about what you mention, but thanks for your advice. and thanks again for the answer, it works as expected.